# PHP convert MongoDB objectID

Tags: php, mongodb

When I get the object id from mongodb that was generated by mongo itself
how can I convert/encode it to base 64 using PHP?

```
$_newCursor = $this->collection->findOne($urlQuery);
$_id = $_newCursor['_id'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really need to have mongoID in base64 encoded string you need to do this:

```
$_newCursor = $this->collection->findOne($urlQuery);
$_id = base64_encode((string)$_newCursor['_id']);
```

Furthermore if you have a MongoID Object you can extract string id with:

```
$_id = $mongoIdObject->__ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I got confused. I tried many suggestions I'll try this one now. Thanks!